# Xamarin: Updating UI From ObservableCollection (OnPropertyChange() hits, List updates without showing)

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, observablecollection

This is my first ever post, so bear with me.

I am using Xamarin Forms.

I am trying to update a shopping cart style ObservableCollection. My XAML file has a button that executes the command "AddCommand" in the below code. I know this works because the Basket ObservableCollection updates (Checked with DisplayAlert after getting object). I know that the OnPropertyChanged() gets called as I have put a breakpoint there and it flags.

My Issue is that the UI does not update after this addition. If I add objects to begin with these load fine, only the objects added using the AddToBasket function fail to show.

BasketViewModel.cs:

```
namespace SacredGrounds.ViewModel
{
    public class BasketViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        ObservableCollection<BasketItem> _Basket;

        public ObservableCollection<BasketItem> Basket
        {
        get { return _Basket; }
        set
        {
            _Basket = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public BasketViewModel()
    {
        Basket = new ObservableCollection<BasketItem>();
    }



    public ICommand AddCommand => new Command(AddToBasket);

    private async void AddToBasket()
    {
        Basket.Add(new BasketItem { BasketItemType = BasketItemType.Drink, ProductName = "Test", ProductImage = "coffeeBeans.png", UnitPrice = 2, Quantity = 1 });
        await NavigationService.Instance.SwitchToDrinks();
    }
}
```

ViewModelBase.cs

```
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Xamarin.Forms;

    namespace SacredGrounds.ViewModel.Base
    {
        public class ViewModelBase : BindableObject
        {
            public virtual Task InitializeAsync(object navigationData) => Task.FromResult(false);
        } 
    }
```

Relevant part of CartPopupView.Xaml

```
     </pancake:PancakeView>
        <Grid
            Grid.Row="1"
            BackgroundColor="{StaticResource GreenColor}">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="250" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <!-- BASKET ITEMS -->
            <ListView
                x:Name="listView1"
                Grid.Row="0"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Basket}"
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource BasketItemDataTemplateSelector}"
                HasUnevenRows="True"
                SeparatorVisibility="Default"
                SelectionMode="None"
                ItemTapped="RemoveItem"
                Margin="0, 6"/>
```

Relevant part of CartPopupView.Xaml.cs

```
    namespace SacredGrounds.Views
    {
        public partial class CartPopupView : ContentView
        {
            public delegate void TapDelegate();

            public CartPopupView ()
            {
                InitializeComponent ();
                GoToState("Collapsed");
            }
```

Could someone please advise me on why my UI is not updating from this code?

EDIT:
Thanks to Jason for the help in realizing my error.

I was creating a new instance of the class BasketViewModel for each page, thus the items in the Observable Collection were obviously different depending on which instance I was accessing. The way I handled this was to add a Static Instance which I passed between pages.

BasketViewModel.cs

```
    namespace SacredGrounds.ViewModel
    {
        public class BasketViewModel : ViewModelBase
        {

            public static BasketViewModel _instance;

            public static BasketViewModel Instance
            {
                get
                {
                    if (_instance == null)
                        _instance = new BasketViewModel();

                    return _instance;
                }
            }

            ObservableCollection<BasketItem> _Basket;

            public ObservableCollection<BasketItem> Basket
            {
                get { return _Basket; }
                set
                {
                    _Basket = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }

            public BasketViewModel()
            {
                Basket = new ObservableCollection<BasketItem>();
            }
```

Comment: you need to post your View xaml/code.

Comment: Apologies... I have added the relevant aspects from each.

Comment: I'm not really clear on what you're doing - AddToBasket adds an item to Basket, but then you immediately navigate somewhere else?  You also mention OnPropertyChanged but adding an Item to an ObservableCollection should not cause a PropertyChanged event.

Comment: The Basket is for a Cart... the Cart page is on a different screen than the button that calls AddToBasket. The idea is that the details page shows details then you press the button which brings you back to the "Menu" but the item gets updated to the Cart listview

Comment: do all these pages share the same instance of BasketViewModel?

Comment: hmmm... possibly not... I'm a total noob with this stuff. I assume when I state the BindingContext of a Xaml then it creates a new instance of the BasketViewModel, but I thought I dealt with that issue with the _Basket variable as that would keep the Basket values the same regardless of the instance? Am I incorrect in my thinking?

Comment: If you want to use the same VM instance you should pass it around between your pages, or create a static instance in your App class

Comment: BOOM! Thanks for all your help mate! Problem Solved! I am updating the original post with the correct solution.